# HttpClient custom header with bracket - C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, httpclient

I have to connect to a RESTAPI which requires a number of different headers.  One of them is causing me a problem because it has it's name within brackets - the header name is "(request-target)".

This is my code but when I hit the line where I'm adding in this value - it says the "The header name format is invalid"

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("(request-target)", "host date");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Date = DateTime.Now;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "localhost:50414";
int count = client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Count();
```

I have tried

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("(request-target)", "host date");
```

It doesn't fail - but my count for the number of headers does not include this header.  I've tried this code - it gives me the same error about the "header name format is invalid"

```
    HttpRequestMessage httpreqmsg = new HttpRequestMessage();
    httpreqmsg.Headers.Add("(request-target)", "host date");
```

Can anyone tell me how to get around this before I go mad !

Thanks a mill.

Further Update

They have provided a java code - to extract the header details and the name definitely includes brackets.  The headers are used to build a string that is signed with a key from a digital cert.

```
public String buildStringToBeSigned(HttpServletRequest request, List<String> signatureHeaders) {

    Integer counter = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : signatureHeaders) {

        counter++;
        if ("(request-target)".equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
            sb.append(s + ": " + request.getMethod().toLowerCase()
                    + " " + request.getRequestURI() + (counter < signatureHeaders.size() ? "\n" : ""));
        }else{
            sb.append(s + ": " + request.getHeader(s) + (counter < signatureHeaders.size() ? "\n" : ""));
        }
    }


    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the header, or does that mean you are supposed to replace it with the "request target"? I doubt anyone would build an API with such clearly invalid headers.

Comment: Hi - part of the process, is taking all the headers and putting them into a signing string.  They have provided Java code which extracts the header details to build the string.  I'll post this now.

Comment: That still looks to me like it could be a placeholder for you to insert what your "request target" is. At least I hope that is the case, I really stinks when a service uses unorthodox conventions (DataX, I'm looking at you).

Comment: I just got confirmation from then - they are using it in their signing string but not in the headers.  There document is very confusing or I need to learn more terminology !! Full day wasted trying to code this.  Ah well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what is happening is that in the `HttpHeaders` class when you call `DefaultRequestHeaders.Add` it calls a private method called `CheckHeaderName`.

Inside that, it does validation against the header key in your case `(request-target)`.
First, it checks if it's empty, then it checks something called the `TokenLength`. Basically, this check goes through each character of your header key and checks against a bunch of `TokenChars`. The following `char`s are not allowed:

```
40
41
60
62
64
44
59
58
92
34
47
91
93
63
61
123
125
```

And the characters `(` and `)` both equal `40` and `41`.

So it looks like it's baked into the .Net framework that the header key is not allowed for any of the above characters.

The `TokenLength` check is also called when you call `TryAddWithoutValidation`. `TryAddWithoutValidation` also returns a bool if the header was added to the collection, so you can use that in code to see if it was added.

Note: This was checked against .Net Framework 4.7.2

Update:

Since it's easier to view the .Net Core source I also had a look there to see if anything has changed and it's pretty much the same sort of logic.

You can see the disallowed values [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/deee13b99d441cf1906397c54d0c5afcf8385d92/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpRuleParser.cs#L29)
It checks if the header key has its value [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/HeaderDescriptor.cs#L55) which is called from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L1168), since it will return false because it contains invalid characters the exception will get thrown.

Comment: That's not good then.  Would you happen to know if Java would allow these brackets ?  I'm going to go back to the site to see if they can clarify.
thanks for taking the time to answer - much appreciated.

Comment: @AnnR I wouldn't know about Java sorry. The thing is that it's not a valid header. Without the brackets it would be valid. If this answers your question, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Jamie
I ticked the green tick - is that correct.  First time poster ! 
Your answer was very informative.  Thanks again.

Comment: That is correct @AnnR thanks! Sorry couldn't solve your issue but hopefully, you can move in the right direction now. Welcome to StackOverflow!